# MS Access 2007, SQL statement clean up table

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have a table with about 770,000 rows, in which only a few hundred are used! Can I use the standard statement, such as:

```
select * into prod_v2 where id = "29830" or "28392" or "23892" ..........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine this would work, though if your listing of IDs is a long one, you might want to chose another criteria for selecting information from one table to another - else there could be a pretty major performance hit as it goes through your table, trying to match your OR statement for every...single...record...in...that...table.